# How to open Python files in IDLE by default? (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, ide

When I double click a .py file in windows, by default it opens a terminal and executes the file. Is there any way to change the default action to "open with IDE"?

Answer (score 4):

Right-Click > Properties.

Change the default `Opens with` to `IDLE`

Answer (score 3):

or right-click on a `.py` file > `Open with` > `Choose default program...`

Then `Browse...`, until you find IDLE (probably something like `C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat` if you have Python 2.7 installed) ...

Then `OK`, check the box labelled "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file", and ... voilà.

But, not sure it's a good idea, though... I'd better keep the `.py` or `.pyw` files associated with the python interpreter, and right-click > `Open with` > `IDLE` when needed, IMHO ...